# QGIS - YXZ Image Changes during Export to .PDF -- WHY?

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer, xyz-tiles

Hoping someone can educate me here.

**My XYZ Tile image changes during the export process from Print Layout to .PDF, .JPEG and .PNG (see screenshots). Why??**

It might not seem like a big deal but I need to show that the lower area was harvested and I can't if that XYZ image changes!

*MAP IN PRINT LAYOUT:*
[image: Screenshot from Print Layout]

to

*EXPORTED MAP IN ADOBE*
(yellow arrows adding in adobe to highlight differences in images):

[image: Exported Map to .PDF, open in Adobe (yellow arrows added to emphasize difference in images]

IS THERE A STEP I AM MISSING TO FLATTEN THE IMAGE, ETC? I AM SELF-TAUGHT IN GIS/QGIS. PLEASE HELP.

UPDATE/POTENTIAL SOLUTION:
USER30184 noted that the export was grabbing higher quality imagery, to circumvent this I exported as PNG and dropped the DPI to 200. Might have been a fluke but it kept the imagery I wanted.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of QGIS? If not, could you please try it and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Where does the background imagery come? The exported map is using higher resolution tiles than what are used on screen for the print layout. Obviously there are tiles from older imagery in some cache and PDF export gets them.

Comment: I'm using Hannover 3.16.13, just updated to double check I'm running the recent version

Comment: @user30184  Its an XYZ Tile from ESRI. You're definitely on to something there, when I zoomed in to edit vertexes before going to print layout it would change over to the imagery in the second screenshot shown above. Is there a way to keep the lower quality imagery then...? Export to PNG/JPEG and keep the dpi low...? Gunna give that a try.

Comment: Please write the trick to use lower DPI as an answer.